# get all script files in asp.net page

Tags: asp.net, javascript

is there a way to find all script files added to a page in asp.net code behind? i am trying to add script dynamically but would like to check first if it already exist on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, no. Other developers can just add `<script>` tag on the fly and not through the .NET objects.

If you ensure that everyone uses [ScriptManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.aspx), then you can use GetRegistered* methods on the object.

Answer (score 0):

If it's inline script, you can use [ClientScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/btf44dc9.aspx) which uniquely identifies a script by its type and key and will make sure it's registered only once.